# Throw exception using conditional (ternary) operator in Java

Tags: java, exception, conditional-operator

I am trying to throw exception when the controlled parameter is `null` as shown below:

```
public static Type getAdapterType(AuthType authType) {
    return (authType == null ? 
        throw new ProviderTypeNotFoundException(authProviderType.name()) : 
        Type.valueOf(authType.name()));
}
```

Here is my `Type` and `Type`:

```
public enum Type {

    private final String name;

    private Type(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

```
public enum AuthType {
    TYPEA, TYPEB, TYPEC
}
```

So, why I am I unable to use `throw` in the ternary operator as the other values e.g. `null`? When I try as shown above, it gives *"';' expected"* or *"')' expected"* errors. But even I add necessary signs, etc. the problem is not fixed. Any idea?

On the other hand, can I use the ternary operator with `orElseThrow`? Do I make the result `Optional` for this?

Comment: Can you change the return type to `Optional`? That will open up a different way of solving this problem.

Comment: @maloomeister Thanks a lot, that page seems to helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

In a Ternary operator, both of your clauses must return a value. So obviously you can't throw an `Exception` there. If you want to throw an Exception then you can use the `if` condition.